# How to tell GDB to flush the stdio of the program being debugged

Tags: debugging, gdb, buffer, stdio

The stdio is usually buffered. When I hit a breakpoint and there's a printf before the breakpoint, the printed string may still be in the buffer and I can not see it.

I know I can flush the stdio by adding some flush code in the program.
Without doing this, is there any way to tell GDB to flush the stdio of the program being debugged after GDB stops? This way is more friendly when debugging a program.

Comment: It seems that GDB has no such mechanism. There are only workarounds.

Comment: related, possible dup of https://stackoverflow.com/q/14858262/11107541

Answer (score 16):

Many recent UNIX stdio implementations will flush all buffers if you call `fflush(NULL)`:

```
(gdb) call fflush(0)
```

If you don't have `libc` debug symbols installed, you may have to tell GDB about the type of `fflush`:

```
(gdb) call ((void(*)(int))fflush)(0)
```

But normally you shouldn't have to do that: if you called `printf` (and not `fprintf`), that goes `stdout`, which goes to your terminal, which would normally be line-buffered. So, so long as your `printf` printed a new line, the buffer would have been flushed after `printf` returned.

Comment: The behaviour of `fflush( NULL )` is well-defined as flushing *all* output streams. Any implementation *not* doing this is not standard-compliant.

Comment: It works very well in my WinXP + MinGW + GDB, thanks.

Comment: Just make sure you don't do this from *inside* a stdio function that might be holding locks on some `FILE` objects, to avoid deadlock or corruption.  (i.e. you can't safely do this at an arbitrary point in a program you interrupt while it's running.)

Comment: I get: 'fflush@plt' has unknown return type; cast the call to its declared return type

Comment: @Rebroad So do what it tells you to? Something like `call ((void(*)(int))fflush)(0)`. Or install libc6-dbg or similar, so GDB knows the type of `fflush`.

Answer (score 3):

GDB lets you call C functions directly from the command line. So you could do

```
(gdb) call setbuf(stdout, NULL)
```

Now, the only problem with that is that I don't know of a way to 'get' the *real* value of `stdout` at runtime.

**EDIT** This might help (from [the docs](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/glibc/libc_241.html)):

```
call setbuf(fdopen(1, "w"), 0)
```

Comment: @Yorkwar: Found a possible 'hacky' way to get setbuf to work on the stdout fd via a duplicate stream object. Don't know about side-effects. Could you give it a whirl?

Comment: `(gdb) call setbuf(stdout, 0)`  works. My probram is in C. But the solution is gdb tells the program, not gdb do it itself. And buffer for stdio is disabled all the time, which can affect the performance of the program. However, it's a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

If you define a function in your program:

```
void flush_all(void) {
    fflush(NULL);
}
```

you can call this function from within `gdb(1)` with:

```
call flush_all()
```

A short demo:

```
$ cat cat.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    printf("this is a partial write");
    printf("this is a partial write");
    printf("this is a partial write");
    printf("this is a partial write");
    printf("this is a partial write");

    return 0;
}

void flush_all(void) {
    fflush(NULL);
}

$ gcc -g -o cat cat.c
$ gdb
GNU gdb (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.2-1ubuntu11) 7.2
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
(gdb) file cat
Reading symbols from /home/sarnold/tmp/cat...done.
(gdb) break printf
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400428
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/sarnold/tmp/cat 

Breakpoint 1, __printf (format=0x4006bc "this is a partial write") at printf.c:30
30  printf.c: No such file or directory.
    in printf.c
(gdb) cont
Continuing.

Breakpoint 1, __printf (format=0x4006bc "this is a partial write") at printf.c:30
30  in printf.c
(gdb) cont
Continuing.

Breakpoint 1, __printf (format=0x4006bc "this is a partial write") at printf.c:30
30  in printf.c
(gdb) call flush_all()
this is a partial writethis is a partial write(gdb) ^CQuit
(gdb) quit
```

Comment: I think of a workaround with "commands" of GDB:  
`(gdb) commands 1-N  
>call flush_all()  
>end`  
Where N is large number to cover all my breakpoints

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `display` command as in `(gdb) display`, the details of which can be found [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Auto-Display.html).  Once GDB hits an end-of-line character like "\n", the output will be displayed.  You can turn off the display using `undisplay`.